# Sending an email in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel

Hei, am trying to send am email in laravel 4.2 to the registered users in my application but am getting an error i dont know how to go about it
here is my function

```
 Mail::send('emails.email',array('user'=>$user), function($message)
        {
            $message->to(Input::get('email'),Input::get('first_name'))->subject('Thank You for Joining bagagga Savings Club');
        });
```

Comment: Hi, can you show us the error message and the controller that handle this piece of code ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i normally do it.

```
$email =  Input::get('email');
$first-name = Input::get('first_name');

Mail::send('emails.email',array('user'=>$user), function($message) use ($email , $first_name)
{
        $message->to($email,$first_name)->subject('Thank You for Joining bagagga Savings Club');
});
```

To pass a variable to an anonymous function, you can use the use construct.